# Is there a mathematical term, practical application, or area of math that covers a function raised to itself?

Tags: functions, terminology, recursion, tetration, hyperoperation

Some abstract examples would be: $f(x)^{f(x)}$ or $f(x)^{f(x)^{f(x)...}}$
Actual equations I've attempted to look at can be viewed [here on desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o0pu91xiuu)
There seems to be a pattern of common convergence, and a relation to the functions raised to a constant power, but in my searches I have yet to find any meaning or usage.

Comment: Wikipedia calls it [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)–and it lists other coined terms. $f(x)^{f(x)^{f(x)\cdots}}$ can be written compactly as $^nf(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = \sin(x) \quad \rightarrow \quad f(x)^{f(x)} $

Produces a linear repetition of an angry man with a sweet moustache ...

That's literally the only usage I've ever come up with.

Comment: Look at $\sin(x)^{\sin(x)^{\sin(x)}}$ - a very nice exposè for building a bridge over the river Rhine... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(x)%5Esin(x)%5Esin(x)

Comment: Ties in quite well with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854861/area-of-a-mushroom-shaped-curve)