# Area of a mushroom-shaped curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics

Inspired by a discussion on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2854635/find-the-derivative-of-y-e-sinx-sinx-sinx/2854639?noredirect=1#comment5888020_2854639), I discovered the following hybrid function:

[image]

The curves in red are defined as $$f(x)=\exp\left((\sin x)^{(\sin x)^{\sin x}}\right)$$ and the curves in blue are defined as $$g(x)=(\sin x)^{\sin x}$$

The result looks like the head of a mushroom (with a bit of decoration :)

[image]

> **Question:** Consider just one 'mushroom head'. What is the area?

We can rewrite the problem as $$\int_0^\pi\left[e^{(\sin x)^{(\sin x)^{\sin x}}}-(\sin x)^{\sin x}\right]\,dx$$ and we can see that it is symmetrical at $x=\pi/2$, since $\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+x\right)$, so this is equivalent to $$2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left[e^{(\sin x)^{(\sin x)^{\sin x}}}-(\sin x)^{\sin x}\right]\,dx\tag{1}$$

Wolfram Alpha calculates this definite integral to be around $3.88407$ (not equal to, as pointed out in the comments.

So how should I tackle this integral? I do not anticipate a closed form, hence approximations would be fine.

> **Update:** I have approximated the functions into simpler ones, to give a value of $3.86029$.

Comment: Is that $(\sin x)^{\sin x}$ or $\sin(x^{\sin x})$ ?

Comment: @DarkMalthorp : Wouldn't $(\sin x)^{\sin x}$ be $\sin^{\sin x} x$?

Comment: Ah yes I suppose so. I personally completely hate that notation and so I never use it but thanks for the clarification

Comment: using the command `N[2*Int[Exp[Sin[x]^(Sin[x]^Sin[x]) ] - Sin[x]^(Sin[x]),{x,0,Pi/2}],40]`, WA returns `3.8840669854123474566360415029651865604369...`

Comment: +1 for the mushroom drawing

Comment: I believe your $3.88407$ is an approximate value obtained numerically. There should be a button for more digits. If it is exact there will be a button for the exact form.

Comment: In fact this integral has no closed form...

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Looks like it. The inverse symbolic calculator [can't find anything](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced) either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Curve approximation**

Over the interval $[0,\frac\pi2]$, the function $a(x)=\exp\left(\sin x^{\sin x^{\sin x}}\right)$ can be approximated by the function $$\alpha(x)=\frac53\sin x+1,$$ and similarly, the function $b(x)=\sin x^{\sin x}$ can be approximated by the function $$\beta(x)=\frac{0.85x\ln\left(0.66x\right)}{e^x}+1.$$ They are shown below, along with the original functions.

[image]

The function $\alpha$ is easy to integrate. We get $$\mathcal I_1=\int_0^{\pi/2}\alpha(x)\,dx=\left[x-\frac53\cos x\right]_0^{\pi/2}=\frac\pi2-\frac53.$$

The function $\beta$ is more difficult. Using WolframAlpha, we get [$$\mathcal I_2=\int_0^{\pi/2}\beta(x)\,dx\approx1.30732.$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+0.85xe%5E-xln%7B0.66x%7D%2B1+from+0+to+pi%2F2) To approximate this integral by hand, we could use the Taylor series for $\ln$ and $\exp$, but of course, this could only be limited to a number of terms (practically), as long rational functions are also extremely hard to integrate.

Hence the definite integral we want is $$\int_0^\pi a(x)-b(x)\,dx\approx2(\mathcal I_1-\mathcal I_2)=\pi+\frac{10}3-2\times1.30732=3.86029$$ with an error of around $0.61\%$.